# Specify the path where to import a python module

Tags: python-3.x, package

In my project I call a specific package called ete3 installed into my Python3 environment here:

```
 /beegfs/home/me/.conda/envs/mypython3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ete3/...
```

I first open Python3.7:

```
/beegfs/home/me/.conda/envs/mypython3/bin/python3.7
```

and I call the ete3 package :

```
from ete3 import *
```

but `ete3` does not come from `/beegfs/home/me/.conda/envs/mypython3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ete3/`

but from `/beegfs/data/soft/python_modules/ete3/` instead.

Does someone know how to get the good ete3 package? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/beegfs/data/soft/python_modules/ete3/')

from ete3 import *
```

Comment: Humm I'm not sure you understood the isue, I succed to import ete3 that is not the issue here, the issue is that I would like to charge ete3 that is present exaclty here : `/beegfs/home/me/.conda/envs/mypython3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ete3/`